# calling node and uglifyjs from Php context

Tags: php, node.js, shell, uglifyjs

I'm trying out the JS minifier library UglifyJS2. I installed node.js on my mac using homebrew, and then uglifyjs through npm. It all works fine in the shell, node is found in the path and I manually added "uglifyjs" to the path so can find it just by typing "uglifyjs" (it is installed here: /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs). This is done in ".bash_profile".

So, I can run everything fine in the terminal. I would now like to run it in a web context, in a Php page, using php's "exec". However, when I try to do that, exec returns status code '127', which I think means "command not found". I tried calling the complete path above too, but with the same result. My web server is running as the same user as i use in the shell.

The uglifyjs program starts like this, maybe that's a problem?

```
 #! /usr/bin/env node
 // -*- js -*-
 ...
```

Is there any way you know of to do this?
Thanks

Comment: If you run `exec()` using the full path (`/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/uglify-js/bin/uglifyjs`) does it work?

Comment: I had also wanted to do what you wanted to do (using uglify on NodeJS via PHP). I tried using packer/uglify to make code harder to read, however, after running through eval / JSbeautifier, I find that the code can still be 'recovered' enough for re-engineering or study purpose...

Comment: If you want something on PHP to compress scripts on the fly, you can try munee

Comment: Also, if you you run `exec('echo $PATH');` do you get the output you're expecting?

Comment: Try using exec on a know workable command/executable script first, then with your nodejs application, check permissions and mode...

Comment: André, no I don't get the ouput im excpecting! I only get this: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Node is installed here: /usr/local/bin/

Comment: Thanks Aaron munee looks interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A symlink in "/usr/bin" did the job:

sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/node node