# exec uglifyJS with php

Tags: php, cmd, exec

I try to exec a simple cmd (which works on my terminal server), but not in my php script.
I use UglifyJS2.
It install in my `/home/MY_USER/node_modules/uglify-js/`

I have chmod the symlink like here: [calling node and uglifyjs from Php context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896515/calling-node-and-uglifyjs-from-php-context).
But

```
exec(/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/uglifyjs ...);
```

or

```
exec(/usr/bin/uglifyjs ...);
```

doesn't work.

I haven't chmod my /home/ of course, but it's maybe the reason why doesn't works?

How can I do exec uglify by my php?

Comment: You're missing quotes in the arguments to `exec()`. Is that just a copying error?

Comment: If that's PHP code you've posted samples of above, it's never going to work until you fix the syntax errors caused by missing `'`/`"` quotes...

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the syntax errors the apache (or web server) user will need exec permissions for the dir and bin.  Why not install it in /usr/bin?